# Any setup to version control ALL ubuntu settings?

Tags: unity, compiz, bash, gsettings

Just now, I had to google for the **third** time in my life on how to disable that thing
in Ubuntu, where you hold the super key and a help window pops up.
Granted, there was a few months in between, but I shouldn't have to remember these things anyway.

And even if I had perfect memory, I still don't want to

1. Launch `ccsm`
2. Navigate to Ubuntu Unity plugin
3. Search where in these 4 tabs is the option that I want
   to disable that I've disabled times before, and there's no
   conceivable scenario where I'd want to use it.

Note here that I have nothing against this setting being enabled by default:
maybe it's actually helpful to a lot of new people.

I just want to have an option to disable it once and for all for all my systems.
My plan is to version control all these settings, and each time I make
a change in the GUI, I'll make a patch that does it automatically next time.

The question is *where are these settings*? I think they're stored in xml somewhere.

Here's the current state of my patch:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme 'New Wave'
```

I don't know if I can set all the settings with just gsettings, maybe there are
more tools that do this.

Answer (score 0):

Those settings are all within your home folder, so backing up `.config`, `.gnome` and so on should do the trick. You can use `unison` to sync those across devices.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the `so on` part. That's the reason why I asked the question.